# Superfish menu color?

Tags: css, superfish

How do I change the color of the superfish menu?

Comment: Could you please specify what exactly a "superfish menu" is?

Comment: @TonyC The author of superfish deems superfish as "Suckerfish on 'roids". It is a jQuery plugin for dropdown menus.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Edit superfish.css, and modify the colors in the following (comments added):

```
.sf-menu a, .sf-menu a:visited  {
    /* text color */
    color:          #13a;
}
.sf-menu li {
    /* box color for top-level menu items */
    background:     #BDD2FF;
}
.sf-menu li li {
    /* box color for second-level menu items */
    background:     #AABDE6;
}
.sf-menu li li li {
    /* box color for third-level menu items */
    background:     #9AAEDB;
}
.sf-menu li:hover, .sf-menu li.sfHover,
.sf-menu a:focus, .sf-menu a:hover, .sf-menu a:active {
    /* box color for menu items when the mouse hovers over them */
    background:     #CFDEFF;
    outline:        0;
}
```